# How to use auto increment to save log

Tags: mysql, database

I want to make a table to save the user log ( for example : login record)
Can the table check the id when using the auto increment ?

Example : 
userid times login_record

1. 1         1         xxxxx
2. 2         1         xxxyy
3. 1         2         xxyyy
4. 1         3         xyyyy
5. 2         2         xxxxx

Comment: Can you explain the scenario a bit more please

Answer (score 0):

not the way you mean, no.  Mysql will not automatically look up the last row in the logins table with a matching `user_id` and increment the `times` field.

the mysql auto-increment is for the internally generated row id, not for column values.

If you insert one row for every login, you can get the user logins count by querying the table, `select count(*) from logins where user_id = 1`.  If you add an index on user_id, this query will run pretty quick.